# I get java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when translating c++ code into java code

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve this problem

https://vjudge.net/problem/UVALive-6805

I found solution but in c++ , Can anybody help me converting it to java code. I'm very newbie to programming

I tried a lot of solutions but non of them work.

Please I need help in this if possible

*I don't know for example what is the equivalent for **.erase** function in c++ in java 
Also is is sbstr in c++ provide different result from java ?*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int syllable(string word)
    {
        int L = word.size();
        int syllable;

        if (L>=7)
        {
            syllable = 3;
        }
        else if (L==6)
        {
            int indicator = 0;

            for (int k=0; k<=L-2; k++)
            {
                string subword = word.substr(k, 2);
                if (subword == "ng" || subword == "ny")
                {
                    indicator++;
                }
            }

            if (indicator == 0)
            {
                syllable = 3;
            }
            else
            {
                syllable = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (L == 4 || L == 5)
        {
            syllable = 2;
        }
        else if (L == 3)
        {
            char Char = word[0];

            if (Char=='a' || Char=='A' || Char=='e' || Char=='E' || Char=='i' || Char=='I' || Char=='o' || Char=='O' || Char=='u' || Char=='U')
            {
                syllable = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                syllable = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            syllable = 1;
        }

        return syllable;
    }

    int main()
    {
        string word;

        int T;

        cin >> T;

        for (int i=1; i<=T; i++)
        {

            int syl[] = {0, -1, -2, -3};
            string rhy[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

            int verse = 0;

            int stop = 0;

            while (stop == 0)
            {
                cin >> word;

                int L = word.size();

                char end = word[L-1];

                if (end == '.')
                {
                    stop = 1;
                }

                if (word[L-1] == ',' || word[L-1] == '.')
                {
                    word = word.erase(L-1, 1);
                    L = word.size();
                }

                if (verse<=3)
                {
                    syl[verse] = syl[verse] + syllable(word);
                }

                if (end == ',' || end == '.')
                {
                    if (verse<=3)
                    {
                        rhy[verse] = word.substr(L-2, 2);
                    }

                    verse++;

                    if (verse<=3)
                    {
                        syl[verse] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            int A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0;

            for (int k=0; k<4; k++)
            {
                if (syl[k] >= 8 && syl[k] <= 12)
                {
                    A = A + 10;
                }
            }

            for (int k=0; k<2; k++)
            {
                if (rhy[k] == rhy[k+2])
                {
                    B = B + 20;
                }
            }

            for (int k=0; k<2; k++)
            {
                if (syl[k] == syl[k+2])
                {
                    C = C + 10;
                }
            }

            if (verse > 4)
            {
                D = (verse - 4) * 10;
            }

            int E = A + B + C - D;

            cout << "Case #" << i << ": " << A << " " << B << " " << C << " " << D << " " << E << endl;         
        }
    }
```

here is my trying

```
import java.util.*;

public class First {

    public static int syllable(String word) {
        int L = word.length();
        int syllable;

        if (L >= 7) {
            syllable = 3;
        } else if (L == 6) {
            int indicator = 0;

            for (int k = 0; k < L - 3; k++) {
                String subword = word.substring(k, 2);
                if (subword == "ng" || subword == "ny") {
                    indicator++;
                }
            }

            if (indicator == 0) {
                syllable = 3;
            } else {
                syllable = 2;
            }
        } else if (L == 4 || L == 5) {
            syllable = 2;
        } else if (L == 3) {
            char Char = word.charAt(0);

            if (Char == 'a' || Char == 'A' || Char == 'e' || Char == 'E' || Char == 'i' || Char == 'I' || Char == 'o'
                    || Char == 'O' || Char == 'u' || Char == 'U') {
                syllable = 2;
            } else {
                syllable = 1;
            }
        } else {
            syllable = 1;
        }

        return syllable;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word;

        int T;

        T = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++) {

            int syl[] = { 0, -1, -2, -3 };
            String rhy[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

            int verse = 0;

            int stop = 0;

            while (stop == 0) {

                word = sc.next();

                int L = word.length();

                char end = word.charAt(L-1);

                if (end == '.') {
                    stop = 1;
                }

                if (word.charAt(L-1) == ',' || word.charAt(L-1) == '.') {

                    word.substring(L-1, 1);
                    L = word.length();
                }

                if (verse <= 3) {
                    syl[verse] = syl[verse] + syllable(word);
                }

                if (end == ',' || end == '.') {
                    if (verse <= 3) {

                        rhy[verse] = word.substring(L - 2, 2);
                    }

                    verse++;

                    if (verse <= 3) {
                        syl[verse] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            int A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0;

            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                if (syl[k] >= 8 && syl[k] <= 12) {
                    A = A + 10;
                }
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                if (rhy[k] == rhy[k + 2]) {
                    B = B + 20;
                }
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                if (syl[k] == syl[k + 2]) {
                    C = C + 10;
                }
            }

            if (verse > 4) {
                D = (verse - 4) * 10;
            }

            int E = A + B + C - D;

            System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + A + " " + B + " " + C + " " + D + " " + E);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you use any IDE? Eclipse|Netbeans|IDEA? You should use it and debug your code step by step to solve your problem.

Comment: @bvn13 what about string.erase function in c++ . what is the equivalence in java for it

Comment: Where do you get the error? Could you reduce the code as much as possible to only show the error?

Answer (score 0):

The Exception is thrown by your second and your third call of String substring method. Your beginIndex is higher than your endIndex. As you can see in here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int) beginIndex always has to be lower than the endIndex.

Comment: what about string.erase function. what is java equivalent to it

Comment: If you just want to remove a substring of a string u can just do it like String s = "abcdef"; 
s=s.substring(0,3);
By this s would be equal to "abc"

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, there are some important points to mention in regards to Strings and Java in general.

- [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) are immutable (This also applies to C++). This means that no method called on a String will change it, and that all methods simply return new versions of the original String with the operations done on it
- The [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) method in java has two forms.

  1. One takes in `beginIndex` and returns everything from `beginIndex` to `str.length() - 1` (where `str` represents a String)
  2. The other takes in the `beginIndex`, and the `endIndex`, and returns everything from `beginIndex` to `endIndex - 1`. The `beginIndex` should never be larger than `endIndex` otherwise it throws an [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html)
- C++'s substring method ([`string::substr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)) takes in the beginning "index" and takes in the number of characters after it to include in the substring. So by doing `substr(L-2, 2)` you get the last two characters of the string.
- Java will never allow you to go out of bounds. That means you need to constantly check whether you are within the bounds of anything you are iterating through.

With all this in mind, I would go and verify that all of the `substring()` method calls are returning the proper range of characters, and that you are properly reassigning the values returned from `substring()` to the proper variable.

To mimic C++'s `string::erase()`, depending on what part of the word you want to erase, you want to get the substring of the part before and the substring of the part after it and add them together.

Ex. Lets say I have a `String line = "I do not like the movies";` Since it is impossible for anyone to not like movies, we want to cut out the word `not`

We do this by doing what I said above

```
String before = line.substring(0, 5); // This gives us "I do " since it goes up to but not including the 5th index.
String after = line.substring(5 + 3); // This gives us the rest of the string starting after the word "not" because not is 3 characters long and this skips to the 3rd index after index 5 (or index 8)

line = before + after; // This'll add those two Strings together and give you "I do like the movies"
```

Hope this helps!